# ASP.NET EventHandling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a servercontrol for ASP.Net. For being short and precise I
just list the things I do:

(1) Call EnsureChildControls in OnInit

(2) Create a dynamic table in CreateChildControls:

```
Table aTable = new Table();
aTable.ID = this.ID + "$" + T;
TableRow aRow = new TableRow();
aRow.ID = aTable.ID + "$R" + <COUNTER>.ToString();
TableCell aCell = new TableCell();

createLinkButton(row, col, caption, aCell, aRow.ID);

this.Controls.Add(aTable);
```

(3) Have a function like:

```
void aLinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Some stuff
    return;
}
```

(4) Have a function like:

```
void createLinkButton(int row, int col, string caption, TableCell aCell, string baseID) {
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.ID = baseID + "$" + row.ToString() + col.ToString();
    lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(aLinkButton_Command);
    lb.Text = caption;
    lb.CommandName = "<command>";
    aCell.Controls.Add(lb);
    return;
}
```

But: The event is never called. The href is redered for postback, but the wired event never gets triggered.

No ideas anymore :(

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recreate the dynamically created LinkButton on Postback for it's associated EventHander to fire. Rather than explain the whole thing, I would highly recommend that you read Scott Mitchell's [classic article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211031102347/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: Hi,

I've overriden OnInit and called EnsureChildControls. That should garantee that the controls are recreated on postback, shouldn't it?

Sascha

Comment: Nope... I don't believe it should guarantee this.

Comment: As far as I understand, EnsureChildControls determines if a control contains childcontrols, if not it will create them.

How would you garantee creation if not using this function?

Comment: Tried to call CreateChildControls in OnInit: two times the table.
Changed CreatedChildControls to something else (normal function, not overriding), calling it in OnInit: One time, still no events

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding you table to the server controls .Controls collection, e.g.

```
this.Controls.Add(aTable);
```

Doesn't look like it from your code sample, so I expect this might be the problem

Comment: Hi,

I ommit that call, but at the end of CreateChildcontrols it is added to the controls collection.

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

I think implementing [IPostBackEventHandler interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) may help.

In your case you can implement Interface and in RisePostBackEvent you can call your event handler method.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi,

no. not called at all. It isn't a plain control, but something tying different other asp.net controls dynamically together. So IPostBackEventHandler doesn't seem to fit in here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page (.aspx file) where you are using the server control. Make sure that you are adding the control to the page's control tree on both initial requests *and postback requests*. All events are handled on postback requests and if the control that generated an event is not present during the postback, the event handler will never fire.

Comment: The server control is hard wired through a tag in the asp.net code. So it should be added to the control tree on both request types.